# How to create TCP tunnels with Pagekite

Tags: networking, tcp, putty, ngrok, pagekite

I am a complete beginner when it comes to networking and I am trying to set up a TCP tunnel on my machine using [pagekite](https://pagekite.net/support/quickstart/). I want to route all traffic from a TCP address to a port on my localhost, let's say 8080. I would then start a handler on `localhost:8080` to deal with the incoming traffic. I can get this to work with [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) simply by doing `ngrok tcp 8080`, but on a free ngrok plan I cannot reserve tcp addresses and ngrok is rather slow, so I opted to try and use [pagekite](https://pagekite.net/support/quickstart/).

Pagekite normally allows easy tunnelling to an HTTP address, but they have a guide [here](https://pagekite.net/wiki/Howto/Windows/SSHAndTunnels/) about how to use PuTTY along with Pagekite to create a TCP tunnel proxied by HTTP.

I followed their guide but could use some help figuring out if it does what I want it to do.

I am working on a Linux VM, so I first set up an SSH server with openssh like this: `sudo service ssh start`

I then exposed that SSH server using pagekite like this: `python3 pagekite.py 22 ssh:user.pagekite.me`

I then started PuTTY, and configured the Host Name to be `user.pagekite.me` on port 22, setup an HTTP proxy with the proxy hostname `user.pagekite.me` on port 443 and finally created a tunnel from the PuTTY machine with source port 8080 and destination `localhost:8080`.

Now I am not sure what this actually accomplished. I know that the PuTTY machine connected to the ssh server running on my VM and I am able to use the linux terminal from the PuTTY terminal but has this actually created a TCP tunnel from `user.pagekite.me:8080` to `localhost:8080`? Additionally after doing this, if I try to setup the handler on `localhost:8080` I get the following error:

```
Handler failed to bind to 0.0.0.0:8080
Rex::BindFailed The address is already in use or unavailable: (0.0.0.0:8080).
```

Again I am completely clueless when it comes to networking so if anyone could explain what it is I'm doing and if it is even possible to do what I want the way that I am doing it, that would be quite helpful.